# QTP Object doesn't support this property or method error for Infragistics objects

Tags: infragistics, qtp

I have created my QTP scripts in QTP 11 with NetAdvantage 2010 v3 and TestAdvantage 2010 v3. I am running these scripts on QTP 11 with the patch QTP_00709. If I am running the scripts from QTP they run fine. But If I use QC 11/Test Lab and run them as a test set, they would start running and after couple of test scripts will start to fail due to the following error.

```
Object doesn't support this property or method: 'SwfWindow(...).SwfObject(...).SelectItem'
Line (49): "SwfWindow("Home Page_2").SwfObject("MenuUltraWinExplorerBar").SelectItem "Resources","People"".
```

Are there any patches that I am missing for QTP 11?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though when running the scripts sequentially that QTP fails to load the Replay server that is configured for one of the types.  This is something that you should contact HP support for.

Some important information that you should gather before you contact support is if there are patterns to when if fails.  For example is it only after running a specific script that it fails, does it always fail after running n number of scripts.  Any patterns that you see should help for determining the cause of the issue.